# "chown mysql:mysql /data/tmp" command

Tags: mysql, database, linux, ubuntu, command-line

I am on a Linux **ubuntu** machine with **MySQL** installed.

If there is a **MySQL** installation on a **Ubuntu** machine, I saw some people doing the following thing:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /data/tmp
```

I get confused, I know the meaning of the above command, which is to change the owner of `/data/tmp` to user '`mysql`' and change the group of it to '`mysql`' group.

**But (my questions):**

**1.** Why would one run the above command?  If I create a table in `my_db` database, by default, there will be `.frm`, `.MYD`, and `.MYI` files (data files) be created **automatically** by **MySQL** under `/var/lib/mysql/my_db/` . So, does the above command changes the default MySQL data directory to `/data/tmp/` instead of `/var/lib/mysql/my_db/`?

**Basically, I would like to know the purpose and effect of the above command.** (better with examples)

**2.** Where does the 'mysql' owner and group come from? Does the installation of MySQL on a Linux machine automatically create the 'mysql' user and group? or People need to manually create a `mysql` account for the linux machine?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Please post future questions about servers to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL needs to own its own directories, as it will be creating/deleting files within that directory. If the dir is owned by some other user ID, then mysql may fail because it can't do whatever file manipulations it needs. Once it has ownership of the directory, it's got carte-blanche.

The mysql user is an arbitrary choice. It could easily be 'fred' instead. But most people use mysql since that's the obvious choice. It's generally created by the package installers if you're installing a distro's pre-compiled version.

Comment: But what are "MySQL files and directories"? Does it refers to those MySQL database files like .frm , .MYD and .MYI ? If not, then by default, what and where are those temporary files your mentioned?

Comment: mysql also creates temporary files to buffer large results sets that can't fit into memory, e.g. when you're doing a sort on a huge chunk of data. It's not just .frm/.myd/etc.. files.

Comment: But I am asking also Where are those temporary files by default ??? For example, those .frm, .MYD and .MYI files are under /var/lib/mysql/my_db/ by default. Where are the files you mentioned located by default???? and normally what is the format of the temporary files? .dat file??

Comment: look at your my.ini/my.cnf's 'tmpdir' setting. and I have no idea what format/name the temp files have. mysql does all the work with them, so you'd only ever have to worry about them if something blew up and they start piling up and using up space.

Answer (score 2):

Mist distributions's MySQL package will ensure the `mysql` user (and group) exists. Then, if you set up MySQL so it stores it's temporary files in `/data/tmp`, you'll want to have it owned by `mysql:mysql`. It will be used whenever MySQL requires use of a temporary table (amongst a few other cases).

Comment: But what are the temporary files refers to? Does it refers to those MySQL database files like .frm , .MYD and .MYI ? If not, then by default, what and where are those temporary files your mentioned?

Comment: It'll refer to *temporary* table, so it could be .frm/.myi as well as something else, depending on what engine MySQL uses for it's temporary tables. I'm not sure what the default location is, it may well depend on the distribution if you're installing from binary packages.

Answer (score 1):

For question 2), If you are installing from source, you need to create the user and group yourself.  From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installing-source-distribution.html :

```
# Preconfiguration setup
shell> groupadd mysql
shell> useradd -g mysql mysql
```